# Что происходит с рублём?

Tags: синтаксис, фразеология

Слышим из СМИ почти каждый день: «По отношению к доллару рубль вырос на рубль 26 копеек». То же самое, но правильно и понятно, можно сформулировать?

Хорошо б определиться в вопросе что есть товар, а что — деньги. Есть мнение, что на нашей территории меняться может лишь стоимость товара, выраженная в наших рублях.

Comment: Вопрос о товаре и деньгах -  это не сюда. Но вообще-то деньги - тоже товар.  Правда здесь это совершенно не существенно. Идет речь о курсе обмена,  а не займа. Так что товара как такового нет.

Comment: Дело в том, что (1) рубль вырасти на рубль не может, ибо станет равен двум, а растёт или нет его покупательная способность, и (2) с некоторых пор и надолго рубль является единственной денежной единицей для расчётов в РФ и равен он самому себе, как эталонный метр, к примеру.

Comment: *Дело в том, что (1) рубль вырасти на рубль не может, ибо станет равным двум* - не принимаю. **Двум** не станет. У нас  одна валюта - рубль. А не "рубль" - одна, а "два рубля" - другая. И если уж на то прошло, что получится с ребенком ростом один метр, когда он вырастает до двух метров? "Два  ребенка"? "Ребенок, равный двум"? По мне так он просто станет взрослым. Вы путаете значение физической (ну или экономической) величины и её единицу измерения.

Comment: Полностью соглашусь, а попугаями если и мерил, то как временным модулем.

Answer (score 3):

> Слышим из СМИ почти каждый день: «По отношению к доллару рубль вырос
>   на рубль 26 копеек».

Это словоупотребление появилось совсем недавно. Точно не скажу когда, но примерно совпало по времени с известными событиями на стыке 2013-2014 годов. Ещё стали говорить «Нефть выросла (/упала)», «Экономика выросла», «Экономика России меньше (/больше) бельгийской», я не берусь судить, правильно ли это сейчас, в 2016 году, но раньше такое словоупотребление не считалась правильным. Нефть не может ни расти, ни падать. И экономика не может ни расти, ни падать. А также между экономиками двух регионов не может быть отношения больше-меньше, типа «Экономика эскимосской деревушки больше(/меньше) экономики папуасской деревушки». Расти и падать могут только лишь какие-то параметры, например, нефти (цена, содержание серы, плотность), экономики, но нефть и не экономика. Также подобная схема словоупотребления перенесена и на рубль. В вашем примере не рубль (фактически) вырос, а вырос обменный курс рубля.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно и понятно: рубль упал по отношению к доллару?  )))

shampar, Что Вам не нравится во фразе? Неужели обязательно надо писать, что ***"Курс российской валюты изменился в меньшую сторону по отношению к валюте американской"?***

Может так и более правильно, но что понятнее - сомневаюсь.

Comment: Простите, но прежде всего ***цитировать*** нужно правильно. Ну коли вам это не ведомо, то объясните, что вам не нравится во фразе, которую вы вынесли на обсуждение?

Comment: Да, так менее понятно, но по другим причинам... "Вырос" - понятие самоочевидное. А "меньшая сторона" - это как? *Меньше рублей* в одном долларе? Или *рубль стал меньше*, чем был (в пересчете на доллары)? Но в чем вы безусловно правы, так это в том, что не надо писать заумно, правильнее фразу это не сделает.

Answer (score 0):

По отношению к доллару цена российской валюты  увеличилась на один рубль 26 копеек.

(Валю́тный курс — цена (котировка) денежной единицы одной страны, выраженная в денежной единице другой страны.)

Comment: Рубль подорожал, а доллар подешевел. Например,  доллар стоил 63 рубля 26 копеек, а теперь стоит 62 рубля. Теперь на ту же сумму в рублях можно купить больше долларов.

Comment: Цена доллара понизилась на 1 р. 26 к.?

Comment: Не цена, а курс. Слушайте, кончайте здесь политэкономию разводить. Мы языком занимаемся.

Comment: *По отношению к доллару цена российской валюты увеличилась на один рубль 26 копеек.* Как это "цена валюты"?  как вообще может быть цена на то, что не продается?! Стоимость обмена, что ли?

Comment: А разве это не следует из определения: Валю́тный курс — цена (котировка) денежной единицы одной страны, выраженная в денежной единице другой страны. Мы же можем "купить" доллары на рубли, или нужно говорить только  "обменять"?

Comment: Это я сейчас подумаю. В том определении явно говорится о продаже. И нет тавтологичности, оно не вызывает у меня отторжения.

Comment: А, так подождите... У вас же не цена продажи там или покупки, а что-то такое "по отношению" к доллару. Вы "отношение к доллару" продаёте?

Comment: Впрочем, ерундой мы занимаемся. Из всех формулировок я все равно предпочту ту, которая автору не понравилось. Мы что, объясняем ему основы банкинга и финансов? Если так, то мы не своим делом занялись, пусть сам и занимается экономическим самообразованием. А если правим стилистику фразы, то это дело безнадежно, покуда не уясним её смысл: не понимая его, можно такого наворотить... Короче я не вижу необходимости улучшать формулировку исходную, пока не станет ясно, что в ней плохо.

Comment: Мне кажется, что валюта может быть и товаром, и деньгами. Если вы покупаете доллары (товар), то платите деньги в соответствии с указанной ценой, которая соответствует котировке.  Если вы покупаете рубли, то ситуация меняется: рубль - это товар, а доллар - деньги.

Answer (score 0):

~1. О понятности. Исходная формулировка абсолютно понятна даже непрофессионалу.
~2. О правильности. Тоже не вижу причин переживать. Правда, это дело достаточно субъективное, готов думать и обсуждать, но прежде всего надо определиться, что тут неправильного по мнению оппонентов такой формулировки. Единственное, что я мог предположить, это использование термина рубль в первом случае в значении "валюта РФ" (выступающая как предлагаемое к обмену имущество), а во втором - как расчетная единица (или, вернее сказать, "масштабирующая единица" такого обмена).
При этом создается впечатление, что перегружая фразу "понятными" формулировками ради отказа от профессионализмов, мы её только портим.

Если действительно возникает непонимание, то максимум, что можно сделать, это дать это соотношение в процентах или в условных единицах, для чего заменить "рубли" (во втором случае) на копейки или пункты.

***«По отношению к доллару рубль вырос на 126 копеек»***. В принципе не вижу необходимости это делать, но если кому-то очень надо... Тут мне если что и не нравится, так это слово "по отношению", но без него, боюсь, не обойтись. Хотя... ***«Курс рубля к доллару вырос на 126 копеек»***. Такое принимается?!

//----------------

Я понял. Автор вопроса не понимает (или делает вид, что не понимает) разницы между физической величиной, эталоном, единицей измерения и значением.

Это примерно как сказать, что никаких киловаттов быть не может, поскольку Ватт (который Джеймс Уатт) был один.

Для тех, кому все еще непонятно, я и предлагал: "***курс*** рубля к доллару вырос на рубль двадцать". Но не считаю это таким уж обязательным. Слово "курс" тут подразумевается, а "рубль" - общепринятое название и обозначение российской валюты. Как аналогичное для всех других.

Comment: *..."курс рубля к доллару вырос на рубль двадцать".* А разве не наоборот: доллара к рублю? Разве под "курсом рубля к доллару" не понимается отношение курса **первого** ко второму, а не наоборот?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Я не совсем понимаю что под чем **не** понимается и почему **не** наоборот. "Курс рубля к доллару" - это первого ко второму, как и следует из написания. "Курс доллара к рублю" - это тоже "не наоборот"  "Курс рубля к доллару"  сейчас  это примерно 60 за 1. Хотя если вы предпочитаете выражать курс рубля в центах, а доллара в рцблях-копейках никто против не будет. Вообще путаница обычно не возникает, если номиналы валют достаточно далеки. Да и слова "рост", "вырос" обеспечивают однозначность понимания.

Comment: Тут вроде всё правильно. Просто ту фразу я бы наоборот записал: *Курс доллара к рублю вырос на рубль двадцать.* Ведь курс доллара выражен в рублях, вот он и может вырасти на рубли, а курс рубля не может, п. ч. выражен в долларах. Вот моя логика.